# Flex identifying end of line

Tags: compiler-construction, flex-lexer

we are trying to correct a mistake in our lexical analysis parser.We are using flex and we have to support multi line strings.The problem is when the end of string is not on the same line with the opening " we do not count the new line.We have two cases of newlines end of line and \n inserted in the string from the programmer is there a way to understand the end of line and count it in the rule some way ?

Answer (score 1):

If you use `%option yylineno` then flex will maintain the line count for you (in the variable `yylineno`). It will get it right as long as you don't call `input`.

There are two small problems:

1. The value of `yylineno` is correct for the last character read, which is the last character in the token. If you have multiline tokens, though, you usually also want to know the line number at the beginning of the token; you will need to store the value of `yylineno` at the end of the previous token.

   Fortunately, you can define the macro `YY_USER_ACTION` to be some C code; this will be inserted at the beginning of every action (including the rules which don't have any explicit action. So something like this will make sure that the previous value is always available as `yylineno_start`:

   ```lex
   #define YY_USER_ACTION  \
     yylineno_start = yylineno_saved; \
     yylineno_saved = yylineno;
   ```

   Of course, you will also need to declare those variables.
2. Flex doesn't track column positions. But perhaps that's ok with you. Otherwise, you can add some more code to the `YY_USER_ACTION` mentioned above. The simple approach is to also save a total character count, and record the total character count at the end of the current line. It's easy to maintain the total character count; you just add the value of `yyleng` each time. To maintain the count at the beginning of the line, you need to check if the value of `yylineno` changed, and if so search backwards in the token to find the last newline character. That only sounds inefficient; most of the time, the scan is very short.

#### Example code

Here is a minimal solution using just line number tracking:

```lex
%option yylineno
%option noinput nounput noyywrap nodefault

%{
int yylineno_saved = 1;
#define YY_USER_ACTION  \
  yylineno_start = yylineno_saved; \
  yylineno_saved = yylineno;
%}

%%
                       int yylineno_start;
[[:space:]]            // Ignore whitespace including newlines
[[:digit:]]+           { printf("Integer %s at line %d\n", yytext, yylineno); }
\"(\\(.|\n)|[^\\"])*\" { printf("String from line %d to line %d\n",
                                 yylineno_start, yylineno);
                       }
.                      // Ignore everything else
%%

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  return yylex();
}
```

And here is a more sophisticated one which also tracks character position, as suggested by point 2 above. This one uses the `yylloc` global variable which is the usual way of communicating complete token boundaries to bison. (Note that this code will not cooperate with either `less` or `more`. If you use those features, you will need to write wrappers for them.)

```lex
%option yylineno
%option noinput nounput noyywrap nodefault

%{
/* The following would usually be generated by bison if you
 * enable location tracking in your bison definition.
 */
struct YYLTYPE {
  int first_line;
  int first_column;
  int last_line;
  int last_column;
};
struct YYLTYPE yylloc = {1,1,1,1};
/* We also need to keep the absolute character position, and the
 * position at the beginning of the current line.
 */
int char_position = 0;
int line_start = 0;

#define YY_USER_ACTION                              \
  char_position += yyleng;                          \
  if (yylineno != yylloc.last_line) {               \
    char* p = yytext + yyleng;                      \
    line_start = char_position;                     \
    while (*--p != '\n') --line_start;              \
  }                                                 \
  yylloc.first_line = yylloc.last_line;             \
  yylloc.first_column = yylloc.last_column;         \
  yylloc.last_line = yylineno;                      \
  yylloc.last_column = char_position - line_start + 1;

/* Just for show */
void show_with_loc(const char* msg) {
  printf("[%d:%d->%d:%d] %s",
          yylloc.first_line, yylloc.first_column,
          yylloc.last_line, yylloc.last_column,
          msg);
}

%}

%%
[[:space:]]            // Ignore whitespace including newlines
[[:digit:]]+           { show_with_loc("Integer\n"); }
\"(\\(.|\n)|[^\\"])*\" { show_with_loc("String\n"); }
.                      // Ignore everything else
%%


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  return yylex();
}
```

Comment: i tried the things you suggested but nothing worked specifically the problem is ,when the rule of parsing the string consumes characters yylineno does not increment and my question is,is there a way of distinguishing end of line from \n written by the programmer in yytext?

Comment: @george: what do you mean by "written by the programmer"? It sounds like you are doing something unusual, in which case you will have to show your code.

Comment: i mean the source file could be like that 
"hello my name is george \n EOL
"
EOL is the actual end of line and \n is for string formatting how to distinguish the difference?
string        \"(\\.|[^\\"])*\"
that is the rule for multi line strings

Comment: @GeorgeXanthakis: `%option yylineno` only recognizes newline characters. `\n` is two characters, a backslash and an `n`. That's not a newline character. I have no idea why `%option yylineno` didn't work for you; you'll have to actually post a [mcve].

Comment: @GeorgeXanthakis: If the problem was the small but obvious typo in my answer (which I just fixed), it would have been helpful if you had mentioned the error message instead just saying "nothing worked" :)

Comment: @GeorgeXanthakis: By the way, see the example code for a slightly better regex for string literals. Yours will not recognize a backslash at the end of a line inside a string, because `.` doesn't match a newline.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the concept of [state or start condition](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/flex/flex_11.html) in Flex.

- Start a state called `<STRING>` whenever you encounter `"` (double quote).
- Inside `<STRING>` state you can write different set of rules, such as - when you get a backslash followed by a new line inside the string , you know it is a multi-line string. You can also detect newline `\n` separately inside `<STRING>` state.
- Upon receiving another `"` (double quote), end `<STRING>` state and return to `<INITIAL>` state.

`source code : string.l`

```
%option noyywrap

%x STRING

%{    
int line_count = 1;
%}

%%

\"   {
                printf("%d: String started\n", line_count);
                BEGIN(STRING);
     }

<STRING>"\\\n"  { line_count++; }


<STRING>\"  {
                printf("%d: String ended\n", line_count);
                BEGIN(INITIAL);
            }

<STRING>"\\n"  { 
                printf("new line\n");
            }                   

<STRING>.   {   
                printf("%s\n", yytext);
            }


\n          { line_count++; }

.           {}



%%
int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    yyin = fopen(argv[1], "r");      // taking input from a file
    yylex();
    printf("\nTotal Lines: %d\n", line_count);
    return 0;
}
```

Try this input.

```
"single line" 
"multi\
line"
```